# Stretch normal/displacement to give entire mesh one color

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Basically, I'm trying to create a material that, when any part of the object is in light, the entire object will light up. I assume this is the easiest approach:

I made a simple material that creates a dot on top of a sphere when light is cast upon it. Now, I'm trying to stretching the dot to the rest of the sphere.

I tried messing around with the displacement, but I haven't been able to stretch it completely. It only goes about a third of the way down (I didn't include this in the photo).

Anyone knoe how to do this? Maybe another method? I have very limited knowledge about normals. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want the whole thing to glow when any part of it is hit by any light?

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm going for. I figured this might be the best approach, unless your have something else.

Comment: Hey, just letting you know I haven't forgot about ya. I tried messing with the nodes for more than an hour and came up with nothing usable. I have some more time later on tonight, so i'll take another look, and if I figure anything out, i'll post it.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks :D I figured out that you could point the sphere's normals upwards in edit mode to make the top half completely white, but the bottom still stays black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of messing around, I finally found a way of doing this. If you stumble across this post seeking the same results, here's how I did it:

- Firstly, I re-orientated the normals of each face of the sphere to point upwards.
- Next, I disabled shadows for the material seen in the image above. This can be done in the material settings.
- Lastly, I created another translucent material that, with the help of a shader to RGB and color ramp node, will only ever be black or white. I assigned this material to the bottom half of the sphere.

[image: the result. bottom texture shown]

I'm satisfied with the result. The cons is that this method will work best with eevee, only work with spheres/simple objects and the top half of the sphere won't cast any shadows.

You can also get something similar by combining a translucent and diffuse shader with the add shader node. This might be better in some circumstances.

I hope this post helps someone ^^